# Google map will not load while on hosting website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Google map will not load while hosting. But it is clearly working on localhost. I changed API key multiple times. but no use. I don't know what the issue is. Please help me.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9KAwLECqv1mfbJVvzoy-otIBTl6gBIN4&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/gmaps.js'></script>
```

Comment: Press F12 and see if there's any console error. post it here.

Comment: Do hide your API key while posting questions like these...

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at '/source/index.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you add more code to how you display the google map?

Comment: I just corrected the  above error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? on line 55.    /* Marker #1 */
    $locations[] = array(
     'google_map' => array(
      'lat' => $lat,
      'lng' => $lng,
     ),
     'location_address' => 'Palayam',
    'location_name'    => 'Loc A',
    );                          Map is loading while commenting this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

well hosting site might be SSL secured. if so try https

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js